# How to Format Time Displayed by Chronometer in Android App Widget as HH:mm:ss?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, chronometer

I am working on an Android App Widget, and I am using a Chronometer to display time. However, I would like to format the time displayed by the Chronometer in the "HH:mm:ss" format. I have reviewed the Chronometer's documentation, but I couldn't find a direct way to achieve the desired format. I have also considered using alternative approaches, such as using a TextView, but I'm unsure about how to implement it correctly within the context of an App Widget.

I have used the Chronometer widget within my App Widget.
I have explored the Chronometer's documentation.
I have attempted to set a custom format for the Chronometer, but I couldn't find a direct way to do it.

I expected to be able to format the time displayed by the Chronometer as "HH:mm:ss" or to receive guidance or code examples on how to achieve this formatting within an Android App Widget using Chronometer or an alternative solution.

Comment: show your implementation